# Как переделать hasOne() на hasMany() в примере?

Tags: php, yii2

Как переделать данный пример используя hasMany() вместо hasOne() для отображения в ячейке GridView нескольких связанных данных из другой таблицы?

**Пример:** [Ссылка на страницу с примером](https://p0vidl0.info/yii2-razbiraemsya-s-gridview.html)

**Данные из связанных моделей в GridView**

Связанные данные выводятся аналогично данным самой модели.

```
// Простой вариант, но без возможности сортировки по полю
'parent.name',
// Вариант с возможностью сортировки по полю
[
    'attribute'=>'parent_id',
    'label'=>'Родительская категория',
    'format'=>'text', // Возможные варианты: raw, html
    'content'=>function($data){
        return $data->getParentName();
    },
],
```

В модели Category  описаны соответствующие методы.

```
public function getParent()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Category::className(), ['id' => 'parent_id']);
}

public function getParentName()
{
    $parent = $this->parent;

    return $parent ? $parent->name : '';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сама связь hasMany() будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
public function getParents(){
    return $this->hasMany(Category::className(), ['parent_id' => 'id']);
}
```

Так же рекомендую писать не className(), а class, т.к. в **yii2** версии ***2.0.14*** оно **deprecated**

```
 @deprecated since 2.0.14. On PHP >=5.5, use `::class` instead.
```

Для вывода всех связанных данных можно сформировать из них строку, примерно так:

```
public function getParentName(){
    $result = '';
    foreach($this->parents as $parent){
        $result .= $parent->name ?: '';
   }
   return $result;
}
```